# Isset in ASP NET view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP NET MVC 4 based and razor. And i have some problem. On page view I'm displaying some information that strore in session. Controller page code:

```
      public ActionResult Index2(EventDetails obj)
        {

                var vm = (EventDetails)Session["EventDetails"];
                return View(vm);
        }
```

And in View page:

```
     <div class="DateTimeSquare">@Model.EventDate </div>
```

But if there is no data ASP NET stoped with critical error. In PHP I can use **if(isset($_SESSION["EventDate "]))**. But what can I do in ASP NET??

Comment: What are the details of the error. Does you view include `@model EventDetails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to set the model to a default when it is `null`, something like this:

```
var vm = (EventDetails)Session["EventDetails"] ?? new EventDetails();
```

Otherwise, you can check it with some c# code in your view:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thnx! first option better for me